# FactoryGirl linting errors, associations, validates_uniqueness_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am working on an RSpec test suite for my project, and I'm using FactoryGirl instead of fixtures. I'm following ThoughtBot's advice about linting my suite before I run it, but I'm getting `FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError` when I lint them, and I know its a problem with my associations but I don't know how to fix it.

The issue comes down to three models:

**Protocol**

```
class Protocol < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

**Record**

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :protocol
  validates_presence_of :protocol
  # belongs_to and validates_presence_of other things that appear to be working
end
```

**Rejection**

```
class Rejection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record
  validates_presence_of :record
end
```

So, `Record` requires a `Protocol`, and `Rejection` requires a `Record`.  Here are my factories:

```
factory :protocol do
  name "Protocol name"
  email "proto123@domain.com"
end

factory :record do |r|
  status "REVIEW"

  association :protocol
  # other associations that are not causing issues
end

factory :rejection do
  message "Message text here"
  association :record
end
```

And when I lint my suite, I get the following errors:

```
* record - Validation failed: Name has already been taken, Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
* rejection - Validation failed: Name has already been taken, Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

It looks like the `Record` and `Rejection` factories are each trying to create a `Protocol` to fulfill those validations, but after the first one, the name in the `Protocol` factory is no longer unique and it's making the others fail. How can I prevent these errors? I'd be fine with reusing the same `Protocol` but I don't know how to do it. I have tried doing it with a `before(:create)` block in the `Record` and `Rejection` factories, but that seems like a brittle way to go about it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Success! I used the FactoryGirl `sequence` method. I had thought it was a private API after (mis)reading the documentation, but since I found the solution in ThoughtBot's own [Testing Rails](https://gumroad.com/l/testing-rails) book (which I bought in beta and which is already very useful), I figure it's legit.

The solution was to specify `name` and `email` in my `Protocol` class as sequences, like so:

```
factory :protocol do
  sequence(:name) {|n| "Protocol#{n}"}
  sequence(:email) {|e| "proto_#{e}@example.com}"}
end
```